# Lower and uppercase with click event

Tags: jquery, symfony, button, click

I would like to put a simple button text in uppercase when I clik, then to lowercase when I click to another button in the list.I have four differents buttons.

Here is my code from my view twig :

```
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" aria-label="...">
            {% for s in secteur %}
                <button id="linkSecteur_{{ s.SecteurId }}" class="text-lg-left btn btn-link z-btn- 
                 secteur" data-id="{{ s.SecteurId }}">{{ s.LibLong }}</button>
            {% endfor  %}
        </div>
```

Here is my code in jquery in order to fix this issue :

```
   $('.z-btn-secteur').on('click', function() {
        if ($(this).data('change', 'true')) {
            //console.log('hello')
            $(this).addClass('text-uppercase');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('text-lowercase');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on each click, remove all uppercase classes from all buttons - Add uppercase class to the button clicked.

Illustration below.

```js
$('.z-btn-secteur').on('click', function() {
        $('.z-btn-secteur').removeClass('text-uppercase');
        $(this).addClass('text-uppercase');
    });
```

```css
.text-uppercase{
  text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" aria-label="...">
            
                <button id="linkSecteur_1" class="text-lg-left btn btn-link z-btn-secteur" data-id="whatever1">text here</button>
                 <button id="linkSecteur_2" class="text-lg-left btn btn-link z-btn-secteur" data-id="whatever2">text here2</button>
                 <button id="linkSecteur_3" class="text-lg-left btn btn-link z-btn-secteur" data-id="whatever3">text here3</button>
            
        </div>
```

Comment: Hello Stender, thank you very much for your help, it's works perfectly for my needs.